# How can i create anonymous object property from a string

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous

I want to create anonymous object with property which send as a string. Is that possible with reflection or something (from string to anonymous property)

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            object myobject = CreateAnonymousObjectandDoSomething("myhotproperty");
        }

        public static object CreateAnonymousObjectandDoSomething(string myproperystring)
        {
            //how can i create anonymous object from myproperystring
            return new { myproperystring = "mydata" }; //this is wrong !!
            // i want to create object like myhotproperty ="mydata"
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to create a copy of "mydata" of type `object`?? I don't get it

Comment: Consider using Dictionary<string, object>  (property name, property value)

Comment: ... or `ExpandoObject`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do something like this:

```
public static dynamic CreateAnonymousObjectandDoSomething(string mypropertystring)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> result = new ExpandoObject();
    result[mypropertystring] = "mydata";
    return result;
}
```

`ExpandoObject` is basically a dictionary that, when used with `dynamic`, can be used like a type.

Example:

```
var test = CreateAnonymousObjectandDoSomething("example");
Console.WriteLine(test.example);
```

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/DWL8412)